# How to propagete the same code style for entire team?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using Android Studio and there is a code-style file we are using. For now, it works like -> every new team member has to import the file in settings before starting to work on the project.

I tried to figure out - is there a way to include this file somewhere on the project level so, the code style would be applied directly to this project automatically. To put it differently, there is no need to worry about importing the code-style file.

I found one of the solutions where - I am supposed to put this code-style file under `.idea/codeStyles/my_code_style.xml`. Thus an Android Studio is supposed to recognize it and auto-apply to the project.

However, I wanted to make it sure and opened `Settings->Editor->CodeStyle`, there you can choose the code style from the `Project`

[image]

But it generates a new `Project.xml` instead of using the expected one - `my_code_style.xml`

The question is - is there a way to apply automatically the same code-style file for the entire team?

Comment: The common way is to add a build script in CI/CD that checks code style and if non-matching code style is committed build job fails.